# I am trying to use the twilio-ruby gem And I can get text messages to work from the Rails Console but In my controller I am a getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, ruby-on-rails-7

NameError in UsersController#create
uninitialized constant TwilioClient::Twilio
Extracted source (around line #5):

attr_reader :client

def initialize
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
end

In My users_controller.rb

```
 def create

@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully created." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    TwilioClient.new.send_text(@user, "This is sent from the controller")
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

end
end

My twilio_client.rb was copied from gorails and looks like this https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/send-sms-with-twilio/blob/master/app/services/twilio_client.rb

Comment: can you please add twililo gem version?

Comment: Using twilio-ruby 5.72.0

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question what I did was

twilio=TwilioClient.new

twilio.send_text(@user, "This is sent from the controller")

This worked for me